# Improve query by removing sub selects?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

We are using a log table to extrapolate quite a bit of information within our application.  I was getting tired of how long the ORM took to run the queries and the amount of queries it took the ORM to accomplish its task.  However, after spending some time trying to write the TSQL on my own I really haven't improved it enough to want to swap it out?  Could I get a few suggestions on how to improve this query.  Thanks.

Using MSSQL 2005.

Query:

```
select
    [Priority] = 
    case 
        when t0.jm_priority = 0 then 'Normal'
        when t0.jm_priority = 1 then 'High'
        when t0.jm_priority = 2 then 'Urgent'
    end,

    t0.JM_Label as [Job Name],
    t1.jt_name as [Job Type],

    (select top(1) x0.JL_Created from pub_joblog as x0
        where x0.js_jobstatusid = 1 and x0.jm_jobmasterid = t0.jm_jobmasterid
        order by jl_created asc) as [Received Date],

    t0.jm_duedate as [Job Due Date],
    t0.jm_cabduedate as [Job CRB Due Date],
    t3.displayname as [Job Host Site],

    (select top(1) x1.username from pub_joblog as x0
        inner join netinfo_users as x1 on x1.userid = x0.netinfo_userid
        where x0.js_jobstatusid = 1 and x0.jm_jobmasterid = t0.jm_jobmasterid
        order by jl_created asc) as [Author],

    t4.username as [Tech Writer],

    (select top(1) x1.JS_Description from pub_joblog as x0
        inner join pub_jobstatus as x1 on x1.js_jobstatusid = x0.js_jobstatusid
        where x0.jm_jobmasterid = t0.jm_jobmasterid
        order by jl_created desc) as [Job Status],

    (select top(1) x0.JL_Created from pub_joblog as x0
        where x0.js_jobstatusid = 9 and x0.jm_jobmasterid = t0.jm_jobmasterid
        order by jl_created desc) as [Completed Date],

    (select top(1) x0.JL_Created from pub_joblog as x0
        where x0.jm_jobmasterid = t0.jm_jobmasterid
        order by jl_created desc) as [Last Modified],

    (select top(1) x0.jl_notes from pub_joblog as x0
        where x0.jm_jobmasterid = t0.jm_jobmasterid
        order by jl_created desc) as [Last Job Comment] 

from  pub_jobmaster as t0
    inner join pub_jobtype as t1 on t1.jt_jobtypeid = t0.jt_jobtypeid
    left outer join pub_jobsitemap as t2 on t2.jm_jobmasterid = t0.jm_jobmasterid
    left outer join net_ou as t3 on t3.net_ouid = t2.net_ouid
    left outer join netinfo_users as t4 on t4.userid = t0.nu_techwriterid
where  (select top(1) z0.js_jobstatusid
            from pub_joblog as z0 
            where z0.jm_jobmasterid = t0.jm_jobmasterid
            order by z0.jl_created desc) <> 9 AND (select top(1) z0.js_jobstatusid
            from pub_joblog as z0 
            where z0.jm_jobmasterid = t0.jm_jobmasterid
            order by z0.jl_created desc) <> 16 
order by t0.jm_duedate
```

Not really for sure how/where to post an execution plan so I just uploaded it to jsfiddle.net: http://jsfiddle.net/my52z/

Probably not the intended purpose, but it works.

Comment: please post the execution plan... that can show for example any needed indexes and/or point out spots to optimize etc.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest that you post your table and index structure as well. Just from glancing through the code, performance might be impacted more by the structure than the heavy use of joins. Here are a few recommendations:

1. Place an index on columns used in WHERE clauses which are not keys (PRIMARY/FOREIGN). Those on the ON clause of the JOINs should be FOREIGN KEYS!
2. Convert the query into a VIEW or a stored procedure: it will benefit from the stored query plan.
3. If you are reading more often than writing into the table, denormalization of the structure will improve performance. That is instead of storing things in different tables and linking them by joins through foreign keys at query time, you would rather have one wide table with all the columns in it. You use the reference tables to just ensure integrity on insert. After all, "log" entries are not to be updated after writing.

Comment: I'm not really concerned with the performance as much as I'm concerned with the fundamentals.  I can't imagine this is a good way to do the query.  I'm looking for suggestions on overall structure and something like 'don't do so many sub selects you moron, do xxxxx'